# Angular/Laravel views and routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel

I'm starting a new project and using Angular.  I'm new to Angular and appreciate any help:

I've created a new project and added these two lines to my `routes.php` file:

```
Blade::setContentTags('<%', '%>');
Blade::setEscapedContentTags('<%%', '%%>');
```

I then have a route:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('layouts.app');
});
```

That view has this HTML in it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="curveApp">
    <head>
        <title>Curve</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css') }}">
        <script src="{{ asset('assets/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('assets/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('assets/angular/angular.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        @include('home')

    </body>
</html>
```

The `home.php` file has the below HTML in it:

```
<div ng-view>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Curve</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="/register">Sign Up</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/login">Sign In</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Inside of my document root/public I have a js folder with controllers, services, and partials.  I then have two files app.js and config.js.

App.js:

```
var curveApp = angular.module('curveApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'curveControllers'
]);
```

Config.js

```
curveApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/register', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/register.html',
                controller: 'RegisterCtrl'
            });
    }
]);
```

How can I have Angular use the HTML files from project/public/js/partials according to the config file without refreshing the page when switching the HTML view?

Comment: really not clear what your issue is. Did you forget to include `ngRoute` file?

Answer (score 0):

I think your `href` attribute needs to be `href='#/register'` instead of `href='/register'`